# jQuery won't update height

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having problems with the jQuery .height() function.

Final result should be an div with an dynamic height as the text changes. Therefore I have an wrapper div and an content div inside that wrapper. The text is in hidden div's somwhere else in the DOM, and 'imported' with .html() function and an simulated fadeIn/Out with setting the opacity to 0 and then back to 1.

When I try to change the content, the wrapper resizes, but with the old height value. I just can't manage to get the current value of the content div...

This is where the magic should happen...

```
nav.click(function() {
    contDiv.animate({opacity:0}, 200, function() {
        contDiv.html(currCont);
        contDiv.animate({opacity:1}, 200);
    });

    wrapper.animate({height:contDiv.height()},200);
});
```

Comment: you are animating the size of the wrapper before the contDiv gets the contents of currCont, is that what you meant for it to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @MrOBrian says, you are animating to the height before the div has its contents, you may need to call this animation in a callback function as follows:

```
nav.click(function() {
    contDiv.animate({opacity:0}, 200, function() {
        contDiv.html(currCont);
        wrapper.animate({height:contDiv.height()},200);
        contDiv.animate({opacity:1}, 200);
    });
});
```

Comment: The wrong bracket was just an typing error ;) And thank you very much, the first version works great!!

Comment: :) I just realise that my second part was also wrong, I added a second callback function to your first animate (my bad) but the bottom one should work as it will wait till the first animate finishes before animating the height, ensuring the content has been loaded.

Comment: remodifyed your code and my answer to remove the typing error.

Comment: Just tried this one... but I still don't really understand why it all works when the height animation is in the callback of the opacity 0 animation, and why it doesn't when i just call it afterwards... But as long as it works... :)

Comment: If you call it afterwards the animations are asynchronous, so the one after is being called with the original height of the contentDiv (before the `.html()` function is called to put the content in).  Doing it in the callback ensures that your content has been loaded before calling the animation for height.  Animations will work with a constant value, not varying values.